# Creating dictionary objects in python from range

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, range

I am trying to create a nested dictionary objects but for some reason it's not creating a key for every single numbers in the range. I am trying to basically have information for multiple vlans in a dictionary so i can access them like such vlan[0], vlan[1], etc...  However it holds the information for the last value. For example if i put num_of_vlans=2.  I will only have value in vlan[1] no value in vlan[0].  What am I doing wrong here? How can i get the desired result?

```
num_of_vlans=input("How many VLANS do you need?: ")

num_of_vlans=int(num_of_vlans)

for i in range(num_of_vlans):
    print("Enter Information for vlan {0}".format(i+1))
    vlan={i:{'name':input("Name: "),
    'vlan_id':input("ID: "),
    'ip':input("IP: "),},}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num_of_vlans=input("How many VLANS do you need?: ")

num_of_vlans=int(num_of_vlans)
vlan = {}  # Initialized the vlan dict
for i in range(num_of_vlans):
    print("Enter Information for vlan {0}".format(i+1))
    vlan[i] ={'name':input("Name: "),   # Updates the vlan dict in every iteration
    'vlan_id':input("ID: "),
    'ip':input("IP: "),}
print vlan
```

What happened in your code was every iteration you are re-initializing the dictionary `vlan` . It should be updated instead.

Comment: Wow.. I can't test this rn going to bed but I assume this will work!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As Marlon said, you are re defining the `vlan` variable to a new dict in each iteration. To build on his answer, you can alternatively use a dict comprehension (if the previous-line print statement isn't necessary).

```
vlan = {i: {'name': input("Name: "),
'vlan_id': input("ID: "),
'ip': input("IP: ")} for i in range(num_of_vlans)}
```

And it's also worth to note that the two extra trailing commas when you built the dict is unnecessary/redundant.